# Make an HTML Editor/Previewer in Xcode 5 with storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the aim to create an HTML tutorial app, but I have very little objective-c knowledge. I need a way to have users enter html and then display this webpage as a browser would render it. I tried using a UIWebview, but I can't figure out a way to load the files that a user saves. Using the method of live editing would be fine too.

Comment: Not an Xcode question. ----- Take a look at the official documentation, with special regards to the `loadHTMLString:` and `loadRequest:` methods of `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a pretty complex question without a simple answer. You'd probably need to deal with grabbing data from an NSTextField and saving it, then showing that saved text as a local HTML file.